# Android spinners, abusing _id to return other field from query

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I'm considering abusing the `_id` of an Android spinner / SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
// get a cursor from the database with an "_id" field
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, key AS _id, desc FROM type_enum WHERE active != 0 AND cust_id = 1", null);

// make an adapter from the cursor
String[] from = new String[] {"desc"};
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to);

// set layout for activated adapter
sca.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// get xml file spinner and set adapter
mTypeView.setAdapter(sca);

// set spinner listener to display the selected item key
mContext = this;
mTypeView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long key){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Selected key=" + key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
});
```

Is this a bad idea?

Is there a better way of getting the `key` that I need, without running a second query?

(The table does have a unique `id` field, `key` is only unique given the constraints in the `where` clause.)

Comment: it is ok to use key which is unique in given context as _id ... you can also use `ROWID as _id, key`(_id only for Spinner and key for your use) in SQL ... _id will be unique for sure but then in on onItemSelected you have to use  `Cursor c =(Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);long key = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("key"));` ... it's up to you ... i prefer first solution

Comment: @Selvin - Thanks, cut and paste into an answer and I'll accept it.